# Sonoma smb file share icon is a question mark

Tags: mojave, smb, file-sharing, sonoma

I have a machine on my LAN running Sonoma 14.2. It shows up as a share another desktop running 10.14 as a question mark ("?") icon.

[image: Icon for Mac Studio running Sonoma]

I resolved a similar issue with a Linux server by adding `fruit:model = Macmini` to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

[image: Icon for PC running Ubuntu 22.04]

Is there a way to configure Samba in Sonoma similarly? Or any way to change the icon to something that doesn't suck?